# Your app includes non compliant SDK version com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk

Tags: android, flutter, ads, google-play-console, appodeal

I recently updated my Flutter app with Appodeal ads, later I got a message.

Google Play Console:

Your app **** version code *** includes SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID, Device Wifi MAC identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

where can I find in my app SDK com.my.tracker:mytracker-sdk

app>build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1'
implementation ('com.appodeal.ads:sdk:3.0.0.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'adjust'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'appsflyer'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'firebase'
    exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services', module: 'facebook_analytics'
}
implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services:firebase:3.0.0.+'

}
```

How to make persistent device identifiers not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers??

How should I resolve this problem. Do I really need to stop advertising (using appodeal)?

Comment: Are you using the official appodeal plugin "stack_appodeal_flutter " for flutter? Which version do you use?

Comment: @JoRa I use the latest official stack_appodeal_flutter: ^3.0.0 version

Comment: I am also informed on the same issue recently. I removed couple of appodeal dependencies like yandex, unity and some other libraries too but still got the same message from Google. Exactly not sure which library using this tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message i got from Appodeal support. and it seems to work

> Currently, MyTracker has released an updated version, 3.0.9, which
> includes all necessary fixes and to update the MyTracker library,
> please resync your dependencies file with all dependencies, and the
> new MyTracker version will be downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

myTracker is included in the myTarget SDK, which is part of the Appodeal SDK.
Try to exclude the myTarget adapter in the build.gradle

```
exclude group: 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks', module: 'my_target'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an update to version 3.0.9 instead an error occurred, then I changed it to 3.0.0.4 with normal success. Will this version 3.0.0.4 also still get SDK violation warnings from Google Play